# How to get subcollection inside firestore using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried doing `db.collection("posts").collection("comments").get()` and `db.collection("posts/comments").get()` but neither seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subcollections live under a specific document. In order to access the `comments` subcollection of a specific post, you'll need to specify that post ID in the path:

```
db.collection("posts").doc("post ID you want").collection("comments").get()
```

---

If you want to access documents across all `comments` collections, you'll want to [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

```
db.collectionGroup("comments").get()
```

Comment: I am trying to access all the docs in the posts collection and then console.log the contents of the subcollection called comments that is in each doc. posts => randomPost => comments => {comment: "randomComment", commenter="randomCommenter"}. I am not trying to get a specific post's comments subcollection and accessing all the comments collections. I might be wrong about the functionality for the first method.

Comment: It sounds like you need the collection group query that I showed in the second half of my answer. Give it a try, and let me know how it works for your use-case.

Comment: I added a subcollection in 2 docs within the posts collection and added a doc in each subcollection that defines a comment and a commenter. I added this code:

`firestore.collectionGroup("comments").get().then((result) => {
        result.docs.forEach((comment) => {
            console.log(comment.data().comment);
        })
    })`
For some reason it outputs each comment 4 times?

Comment: It's hard to say why that is, but that code should be getting the docs from each collection named `comments` regardless of whether it's under a `posts` document.

Comment: I think it would work if I just get the uid of the post doc and then do `firestore.collection("posts").doc(uid).collection("comments").get()`  I am not sure what the post ID is though, I just assumed it was the uid of the doc.Another problem I am having is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70266259/code-that-somehow-accesses-docs-from-firebase-and-displays-contents-that-i-dont

Comment: Many apologies. It was outputting them 4 times because I added them to the initial component instead of a useEffect or function. I managed to get it to work thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web Modular API for like React or Next JS Try this

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "posts", "post_id", "comments"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Documentation Link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_subcollection