# Code that somehow accesses docs from firebase and displays contents that I don't understand? REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase

The function of the code is supposed to get the docs of the collection called posts and then output the post component that I created for each doc inside it. This is the code:

```
function AllPostsPage(props) {

    const postsRef = firestore.collection("posts");
    const query = postsRef.orderBy("createdAt", "desc");

    const [posts] = useCollectionData(query, {idField: "id"});

    return (

        <ThemeProvider theme={props.theme}>

            {posts && posts.map((title, desc, poster, imgUrl, comments) =>  <Post theme={props.theme} key={title.id} title={title} desc={desc} poster={poster} imgUrl={imgUrl} comments={comments} />)}

        </ThemeProvider>

    );

}
```

I would like to understand this code as I would have initially just done:

```
function AllPostsPage(props) {

    const posts = firestore.collection("posts");

    return (

        <ThemeProvider theme={props.theme}>

            {posts.get().then((result) => { result.docs.forEach((post) => {<Post title={post.data().title} ...otherData />} ) } )}

        </ThemeProvider>

    );

}
```

Comment: Might get downvted, as people may consider this as something you could have found out youself by Googling for a short while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a ReactJS expert, but an `.orderBy()` is used to specify the sort order of your data and by default, a query retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID. In the first code snippet you've posted, it means that the results of the `query`, will be printed in a descending order. Check this documentation for more information regarding [order and limit data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) in firebase.

Additionally, [useCollectionData](https://github.com/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/firestore#usecollectiondata) hook has the following parameters:
`query`: (optional) `firestore.Query` for the data you would like to load, and;
`idField`: (optional) name of the field that should be populated with the `firestore.QuerySnapshot.id` property.

Refer to this [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage) for further instruction and guide in using Firestore with ReactJS.